# Writing multiple csv files in one xls file using phpExcel

Tags: php, csv, phpexcel

Good morning. I'm trying to create a .xls file from three different.csv files placed in the /temp directory from windows. Those .csv files contains data from a database. My problem is that I don't know why the output is way different as it should be. I have three sheets in my .xls document for each of the .csv files, but I only get the content of one of the files, and it overrides the header of the document, changing it. Here is my code

```
/**
 * Cabeceras para descargar el excel
 */
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=informe_de_precios" . date("Y-M-D-h-m-s") . ".xls");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");

require_once '/PHPExcel_1.8.0_doc/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objPHPExcel->
        getProperties()
        ->setCreator("Idiso")
        ->setLastModifiedBy("Idiso")
        ->setTitle("Informe errores precios")
        ->setSubject("Informe errores precios")
        ->setDescription("Informe errores precios")
        ->setKeywords("Informe errores precios")
        ->setCategory("Informe errores precios");

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A1', 'CANAL')
        ->setCellValue('B1', 'COD_HOTEL')
        ->setCellValue('C1', 'NOMBRE')
        ->setCellValue('D1', 'TARIFA')
        ->setCellValue('E1', 'HABITACION')
        ->setCellValue('F1', 'REGIMEN')
        ->setCellValue('G1', 'FECHA_INI')
        ->setCellValue('H1', 'FECHA_FIN')
        ->setCellValue('I1', 'RECUENTO')
        ->setCellValue('J1', 'PUBLICADO')
        ->setCellValue('K1', 'ERROR_DESCRIPTION')
        ->setCellValue('L1', 'ERROR_DETAIL')
        ->setCellValue('M1', 'TRAN_XMLIN')
        ->setCellValue('N1', 'TRAN_XMLOUT');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->setTitle('Precios');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:N1')->getFont()
        ->setBold(true)
        ->setSize(9);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:N1')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:N1')->getFill()->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFFF00');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(-1);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter('A1:N1');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->freezePane('A2');

$objPHPExcel->createSheet();

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1)
        ->setCellValue('A1', 'CANAL')
        ->setCellValue('B1', 'COD_HOTEL')
        ->setCellValue('C1', 'NOMBRE')
        ->setCellValue('D1', 'TARIFA')
        ->setCellValue('E1', 'HABITACION')
        ->setCellValue('F1', 'FECHA_INI')
        ->setCellValue('G1', 'FECHA_FIN')
        ->setCellValue('H1', 'RECUENTO')
        ->setCellValue('I1', 'PUBLICADO')
        ->setCellValue('J1', 'ERROR_DESCRIPTION')
        ->setCellValue('K1', 'ERROR_DETAIL')
        ->setCellValue('L1', 'TRAN_XMLIN')
        ->setCellValue('M1', 'TRAN_XMLOUT');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(1)->setTitle('Cupos');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:M1')->getFont()
        ->setBold(true)
        ->setSize(9);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:M1')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:M1')->getFill()->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFFF00');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(-1);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter('A1:M1');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->freezePane('A1');

$objPHPExcel->createSheet();

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(2)
        ->setCellValue('A1', 'CANAL')
        ->setCellValue('B1', 'COD_HOTEL')
        ->setCellValue('C1', 'NOMBRE')
        ->setCellValue('D1', 'TARIFA')
        ->setCellValue('E1', 'HABITACION')
        ->setCellValue('F1', 'FECHA_INI')
        ->setCellValue('G1', 'FECHA_FIN')
        ->setCellValue('H1', 'RECUENTO')
        ->setCellValue('I1', 'PUBLICADO')
        ->setCellValue('J1', 'ERROR_DESCRIPTION')
        ->setCellValue('K1', 'ERROR_DETAIL')
        ->setCellValue('L1', 'TRAN_XMLIN')
        ->setCellValue('M1', 'TRAN_XMLOUT');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(2)->setTitle('Normas');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:M1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:M1')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:M1')->getFill()->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFFF00');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(-1);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter('A1:M1');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->freezePane('A1');
/**
 * Usamos un iterador para darle estilos a cada columna del excel
 */
$fileSystem = new DirectoryIterator("C:\Windows\Temp");
chdir("C:\Windows\Temp");
foreach ($fileSystem as $tempFile) {
    if (preg_match("/price\d*.csv/", $tempFile->getFilename())) {
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_CSV();
        $objReader->setInputEncoding('CP1252');
        $objReader->setDelimiter(';');
        $objReader->setEnclosure('');
        $objReader->setLineEnding("\n");
        $objReader->setSheetIndex(0);
        $objReader->loadIntoExisting($tempFile->getFilename(), $objPHPExcel);
    } else if (preg_match("/allotment\d*.csv/", $fileSystem->getFilename())) {
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
        $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_CSV();
        $objReader->setInputEncoding('CP1252');
        $objReader->setDelimiter(';');
        $objReader->setEnclosure('');
        $objReader->setLineEnding("\n");
        $objReader->setSheetIndex(0);
        $objReader->loadIntoExisting($tempFile->getFilename(), $objPHPExcel);
    } else if (preg_match("/price\d*.csv/", $fileSystem->getFilename())) {
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(2);
        $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_CSV();
        $objReader->setInputEncoding('CP1252');
        $objReader->setDelimiter(';');
        $objReader->setEnclosure('');
        $objReader->setLineEnding("\n");
        $objReader->setSheetIndex(0);
        $objReader->loadIntoExisting($tempFile->getFilename(), $objPHPExcel);
    } else {
        continue;
    }
    $fileSystem->next();
}

foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    /**
     * Cogemos el index de la hoja activa en el momento para poder iterar
     * entre las hojas
     */
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($objPHPExcel->getIndex($worksheet));

    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $cellIterator = $sheet->getRowIterator()->current()->getCellIterator();
    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(true);
    /**
     * Mediante este foreach le damos el formato que queramos a las columnas,
     * si la columna es "mayor"(alfabÃ©ticamente) a la J se le da un width
     * de 40, si no tiene autoSize
     */
    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
        //print_r($sheet->getColumnDimension($cell->getColumn()));
        if ($sheet->getColumnDimension($cell->getColumn())->getColumnIndex() > "J") {
            $sheet->getColumnDimension($cell->getColumn())->setAutoSize(false);
            $sheet->getColumnDimension($cell->getColumn())->setWidth(40);
            $sheet->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('Calibri')->setSize(9);
        } else {
            $sheet->getColumnDimension($cell->getColumn())->setAutoSize(true);
            $sheet->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('Calibri')->setSize(9);
        }
    }
}

$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

The output that it should make is the following: https://ufile.io/a1a1b

Could you help me with this issue, please? Thank you so much in advance for your time and effort.

Comment: This is the output my code produces: https://uploadfiles.io/5815d

Comment: Press "Ctrl + k" and paste your codes. It's easier to read that way.

Comment: Ok! I edited my message. I did some changes in my code trying to solve this so it's a little bit different from yesterday (still not working anyway) Thank you anyways for your time!

Answer (score 0):

It's already solved, I didn't set the delimiter for the .csv file! thank you for your time and effort and sorry for any inconvenience it may have caused!